# Cleansing special characters from URL search queries

Tags: regex, .htaccess

When I use the search form on my website, the URL ends up like this:

```
http://website.dev/catalogsearch/result/?q=WhatISearchedFor
```

I'd like to make it so that the URL is cleansed of special characters so that if I tried to go to

```
http://website.dev/catalogsearch/result/?q=$What#I&Searched\\For
```

I'd end up at the same URL above

Here is the current rewrite rule I have, but I'm new to regular expressions/htaccess so I'm not sure if it's formatted correctly.

```
RewriteRule ^catalogsearch/result/?q=(/[^a-z0-9\s\']/i)$
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: The special characters are URIencoded character literals so you do not want to remove them in most cases. Instead you URIencode and URIdecode when you work with them as parameters.

Comment: In this case I do want them removed. The site is being targeted by a web crawler that searches for queries full of special characters. These queries then pop up in the "Popular search terms" area so it looks like "Popular search terms: necklace, earrings, necklace\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\".

Comment: You are trying to match against query strings in RewriteRule directive, that is not correct. server may return 500